# Dad tried to upgrade to 15.10, now it wont boot anymore. Can I reset it?

Tags: boot, upgrade, updates, 15.10

He tried to upgrade from 14.04 I believe to 15.10, now after he types in his password it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6uP3.jpg

It's an AIO desktop from asus core i5 with a nvidea 540m connected wirelessly if that is any help.

He fears he somehow screwed something up during the updating process and I am of no help, since I am a complete noob when it comes to typing in any commands and such (which is something I hope someone here can teach me to fix this. He himslef doesn't even speak english.)

I hope to maybe reset the pc to a previous state to keep all his data or maybe even successfully upgrade to 15.10, but again I've no idea where to even begin.

Thank you for reading, I hope I'm not violating any rules this being my first post here.